# Why do I receive an ACCESSING_NON_EXISTENT_FIELD warning after a JOIN and setting of an alias?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

In the following Pig script, my value `ct` "disappears" when I run a DUMP on any step **after** performing the generate that sets the `e3` alias. For example, if I execute a `DUMP` on `e4` immediately after setting the alias, no value is returned.

I will also see the following warning in my output:

> [main] WARN 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   - Encountered Warning ACCESSING_NON_EXISTENT_FIELD 9 time(s).

```
   eng_grp = GROUP engs BY (aid, scm_id,ts,etype);
   eng_grp_out = FOREACH eng_grp
               GENERATE
                   group.aid as aid,
                   group.scm_id as scm_id,
                   group.etype as etype,
                   group.ts as timestamp,
                   (long)COUNT_STAR(engs) as ct;

   eng_joined = JOIN eng_grp_out BY (aid,scm_id), tgc BY (aid, scm_id);

   e3 = FOREACH eng_joined GENERATE
         MD5((chararray)CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(eng_grp_out::aid,'_'),eng_grp_out::scm_id),'_'),eng_grp_out::etype),'_'),(chararray)eng_grp_out::timestamp)) as id,
         eng_grp_out::aid as v,
         eng_grp_out::scm_id as scmid,
         eng_grp_out::etype AS et,
         eng_grp_out::timestamp as ts,
         FLATTEN(tgc::tags),
         eng_grp_out::ct as ct;

   -- the value for "ct" will be output if I do DUMP e3; here

   e4 = FOREACH e3 GENERATE
         id,
         v,
         scmid,
         et,
         ts,
         FLATTEN(tgc::tags::g) as gg,
         ct;
   -- the value for "ct" will be NOT be output if I do DUMP e4; here
   e5 = FOREACH e4 GENERATE
         id,
         v,
         scmid,
         et,
         ts,
         gg#'g' as tg,
         gg#'v' as tv,
         gg#'d' as td,
         ct;

   e6 = FOREACH e5 GENERATE
         id,
         v,
         scmid,
         et,
         (long)ts,
         tg#'\$oid' as tg,
         tv#'\$oid' as tv,
         (chararray)td as td,
         ct;

   e7 = FOREACH e6 GENERATE
         id,
         v,
         scmid,
         et,
         ts,
         'c' as tt,
         tg,
         tv,
         td,
         ct;

   e8 = FOREACH e7 GENERATE
         id,v,scmid,et,ts,tt,
         CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(tg,'_'),tv),'_'),td) as ct,
         tg,tv,td,ct;
```

Comment: What is the output of `describe e4` ?

Comment: `DESCRIBE e3` produces `e3: {id: chararray,v: chararray,scmid: bytearray,et: chararray,ts: long,tagged_content::tags::g: map[],tagged_content::tags::v: map[],tagged_content::tags::d: chararray,tagged_content::tags::n: chararray,ct: long}`

Comment: `DESCRIBE e4` produces `e4: {id: chararray,v: chararray,scmid: bytearray,et: chararray,ts: long,gg: map[],ct: long}`

Comment: Does it work if you do not use an alias?

Comment: I was able to finally get it to work by changing the assignment of the `e3` alias to `e3 = FOREACH eng_joined GENERATE ...kept everything else the same, TOMAP('count_val', (long)eng_grp_out::ct);`. From there I was able to get the value I needed in the `e4` assignment by doing `(long)$6#'count_val' as val`.

Comment: FLATTEN is evil. At least that is my experience with Pig scripting... :D

Comment: @MichaelDeLorenzo, would you mind terribly answering your own question and then accepting the answer after 48 hours so that this disappears from other people's pig questions queue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to finally get it to work by changing the assignment of the `e3` alias to

`e3 = FOREACH eng_joined GENERATE 
//...kept everything else the same... 
TOMAP('count_val', (long)eng_grp_out::ct);`

From there I was able to get the value I needed in the `e4` assignment by doing `(long)$6#'count_val' as val`.